# AVD (emulator) won't start on Linux

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-2.2-froyo

Running Ubuntu Lucid, 32-bit. Eclipse Galileo with Android SDK Tools installed.

After setting up an Android Virtual Device in the Android SDK and AVD Manager:

```
Name         Target Name      Platform   API Level
TestDevice   Android 2.2      2.2        8
```

...clicking the Start... button does nothing--no errors anywhere, no sounds, no window or dialog anywhere, nothing at all.

I've spent the last hour creating, trying, deleting devices and Googling. I can't find anything anywhere about a problem of the start button not working on Linux.

Note that the emulator will start if I simply right-click on an Android project, and choose Run As, then Android Application.

I've done this successfully on Windows for the last month+; I'm a Linux guy and decided to attempt to maintain a parallel development environment there rather than condemn myself to Windows-dependence.

Any comment would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Russ

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a

```
mkdir -p /tmp/android
chmod 777 /tmp/android
```

I've also had the emulator get into a state where it wouldn't come back up without rebooting the Linux machine.